# Odd date output from biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am using biblatex-apa for my references and I have this enty in my .bib file:

```
@ONLINE{habitat,
    TITLE = {Mission, Vision \& Values},
    URL = {http://www.tchabitat.org/missionvisionvalues},
    ORGANIZATION = {Twin Cities Habitat for Humanity website},
    URLDATE = {2011-09-15}
}
```

The output shows the date of the reference as 'Retrieved 15 September 2011 from...'. Shouldn't the date be like the english date format, September 15th, 2011?

EDIT:

This is my preamble

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{apa6e}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\bibliography{libros}
\defbibheading{bibliography}{\section*{\normalfont\refname}}
```

Comment: From the documentation: The ‘american’ babel option will give you APA compliant US date formats

Comment: I am using the 'american' babel option, as well as the recommended language definition in my preamble.

Comment: It seems like a bug in `american-apa.lbx`: the definition of `\mkbibdateapalong` is identical with that in `french-apa.lbx`.

Comment: Interesting. @egreg would you be able to post the correct definition? I'm very new to latex, I read the files but I have no idea where or how to fix the definitions.

Comment: @ravl1084 Sorry, but it's quite complicated and it should be addressed by the package author.

Comment: I have posted this problem in the comp.text.tex usenet group, hopefully there will be an answer.

Comment: I don't think the `american-apa.lbx` file is the problem. I made an attempt to change it from what little I understand it does and there was no effect in the output. Or errors, for that matter.

Comment: The function that's been called is `\mkbibdateapalongdmy`, for elements of type `url` or `event`. I cannot find any APA guide mentioning the date not following english format, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just uploaded version 3.6 to CTAN which should fix this. Thanks for spotting it. I realised that the APA 6th edition manual which I used to write the style has not one example of "Retrieved on" in chapter 7. So, it slipped by me. APA 5th edition had many. Strange really since the 6th edition is so focussed on "new media" formats ...

Comment: Thank you :). On a sidenote, I noticed the output is different for that same bib file when you use biber as a backend. Is this intended?

Comment: Quite possibly - the apa style uses some biber only features and it strongly recommended. In fact, the reason I got involved with biber development is precisely because there are APA style features that require things bibtex can't do (uniquelist).

Comment: I am no expert in APA style, but with the above example I think the biber output is wrong. Like the reference date showing `()` instead of `(n.d.)`. The citation is also different, showing the year of retrieval instead of `n.d.`. Again, I'm no expert but the output without biber looks more consistent to other references. But APA is meant to confuse us all, is it not?

Comment: You're right, something is wrong here - I am looking into it.

Comment: The "()" is clearly wrong but the cite is correct - with biber you can specify a list of fields for labelyear and the biblatex default will make sure that labelyear is set to the url year if there is no real date. So, the citation will be the urlyear as it's set from labelyear. You need to change the labelyear definition if you don't want this (see \DeclareLabelyear in section 4.5.2 of the biblatex manual)

Comment: I have just uploaded version 3.7 of the style that should fix the "()" issue.

Answer (score 3):

To obtain an APA-compliant date (to my understanding) I modified the `american-apa.lbx` file. I changed the function `\mkbibdateapalongdmy` to read as follows

```
\protected\def\mkbibdateapalongdmy#1#2#3{%
 \iffieldundef{#2}
   {}
   {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}}
 \iffieldundef{#3}
   {}
   {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}}
 \iffieldundef{#1}
   {}
   {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{#2}\OR\iffieldundef{#3}}
     {}
     {\addcomma\addspace}
     \thefield{#1}
   }
 }
```

This produces the output date 'September 15, 2011'.

**Disclaimer:** I succeeded in getting the output I wanted, but I cannot guarantee that this won't break something else. As far as I understand from reading the code, the `\mkbibdateapalongdmy` function is called for entries of type `url` and `event` but it might be used in other cases.